# slideToggle() function doesn't do anything

Tags: jquery

I want to slide toggle my menu when someone clicks `i` which i added from fontawesome but it doesnt work i tried everything

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.fa-beer').click(function() {
    $('#aa').slideToggle(fast);
  })
})
```

```css
#aa {
  position: absolute;
  width: 230px;
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
  background: green;
  display: none;
}

#aa ul li {
  padding: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i class="fas fa-beer">Click</i>
<div id="aa">
  <ul>
    <li>Maain</li>
    <li>Maain</li>
    <li>Maain
      <ul>
        <li>maain 2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Maain</li>
    <li>Maain</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: fast must be a string
`$('#aa').slideToggle('fast');`

Comment: I've added text to your button (because font awesome isn't included) and embedded jQuery to turn your code into a reproducible snippet. If either of these changes drastically affect the way in which your code operates, or misrepresent your issue, feel free to rollback my edit.

Comment: ^ I'm also voting to close as "Simple Typographical Error" because, as @arkadij_ok points out, seems like you're just missing some quotes.

Comment: `$('.fa-beer').on('click', function() { ... })` also use this construction for a click event

Comment: @arkadij_ok If not using the delegation argument then I don't see that this suggestion is anything other than personal preference. It's only when you do `.on("click", "another-selector", function() { ... })` that you get any functional difference or benefit.

Comment: Further the previous comments, when something is not working, look at the `console` first. In this case you'll get `Uncaught ReferenceError: fast is not defined`

Comment: @TylerRoper right, `.click` is just a shorter and less flexible shortcut to `.on('click', handler)` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `fast` should be around quotes.

other than that your code is perfect.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.fa-beer').click(function() {
    $('#aa').slideToggle("fast");
  })
})
```

```css
#aa {
  position: absolute;
  width: 230px;
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
  background: green;
  /*display: none;*/
}

#aa ul li {
  padding: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i class="fas fa-beer">toggle</i>
<div id="aa">
  <ul>
    <li>Maain</li>
    <li>Maain</li>
    <li>Maain
      <ul>
        <li>maain 2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Maain</li>
    <li>Maain</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: In the future, consider marking questions like these as "Off Topic > Simple Typographical Error", and informing OP in a comment as opposed to an answer. These answers are generally extremely specific to OP's case only, and therefore unlikely to help future readers. They tend to clutter up the repository of useful knowledge here at SO moreso than bolster it :)

Comment: Just to explain this answer, in `$('#aa').slideToggle(fast);`, compilers read `fast` as an undefined variable. `fast` must be a string to correctly be compiled. So, `fast` should have quotes around it, either single or double. `$('#aa').slideToggle('fast');`